# Swing components taking too long to load?

Tags: java, performance, swing, constructor, jframe

I've had problems with any type of swing component taking way too long to load for about a day now. I tried using a different IDE, I updated Java JDK but any type of swing component takes too long to load, I'm currently using it in my engine to load projects and save, But it takes way too long to show up, So I created an empty program that just does the following:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class main {
public main() {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Save before quitting ?", "Red Engine", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - now + "ms");
}
}
```

and this is the result: 5015ms
So it's taking five seconds to load this up, I'm also having the same issue with just initializing a JFrame.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class main {
public main() {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - now + "ms");
}
}
```

and this is the result: 4505ms

So what the hell is going on with Java ? This is waaay too frustrating. I'm using jdk1.8.0_77 btw.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Since it's got to spin up the Event Dispatching Thread and make the required connections into the core OS, it's probably not all that surprising.  Try and create your UI from within the context of the EDT to start with and see if that makes a difference. See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, when you create a Swing frame/dialog you start the huge Swing machinery. Swing requires minimum 3 additional threads for working, so the starting of a swing application can take slightly longer than a console application (but minimal).

I've tried to reproduce your results, but got only 50ms for the frame creation (80ms total). Even when I initialize all widgets in the main thread I get the same results. For correct result you should initialize all Swing widget in the Swing Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT). Here is my code:

```
public class SwingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // for correct result wee need to do all in the swing thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame f = new JFrame();
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - now);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - now);
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - now);` should be after `f.setVisible(true);`